# Does the state change, when the Hamiltonian changes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, ground-state

Consider the Hamiltonian

\begin{equation}
    H = \frac{p^{2}}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m\omega^{2}x^{2} - \theta(t) qEx
\end{equation}

where $\theta(t)$ is $0$ for $t = 0$ and $1$ for $t > 0$. If at $t = 0$ the state of the system is the ground state, what exactly happens when $t > 0$? The energy levels are shifted by a constant and there will be a new ground state. However the system still is in the former state? That would mean my expected energy value would still just be $E_0$ and the system is with 100 percent certainty still in the previous state (but it doesn't exist anymore, right?). It would also not make sense, if the state just instantly changes to the new ground state.

Edit:
What's the probability to still find the system in the ground state of the old Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At $t=0$ the system will be in exactly the same state it was in before, but that state is no longer an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. The state is a superposition of the eigenstates of the new Hamiltonian and will evolve in time according to the TDSE. In general the change in Hamiltonian will do work on the system, so the expected energy of the state will typically not be $E_0$ with respect to the new Hamiltonian

Comment: Thank you a lot! That would mean, that there is a possibility p < 1 to find the system in the former state. But it is not possible to find an exact value for the expected energy as I don't know the superposition? (The expected value could be found via the coefficients of the discrete energies)

Comment: You can find the superposition. The wavefunction should be continuous at $t=0$, so finding the superposition is simply a matter of expressing the old state in the new eigenbasis (although this may be a rather tedious calculation in practice)

Comment: Calculating the expectation of the new expectation of energy is much simpler, however. Simply sandwich the new Hamiltonian with the old ground state.

Comment: For the new Hamiltonian I reveive

\begin{equation}
    E_0 = \frac{\hbar \omega}{2} - \frac{q^2E^2}{2m\omega^2}
\end{equation}

This is smaller than the ground state of the old Hamiltonian, which was $\frac{\hbar \omega}{2}$. I really don't know how to calculate the expected energy now. I never heard of sandwiching the Hamiltonian. The only thinking of would be calculating

\begin{equation}
    p_n = |\bra{\Phi_n}\ket{\Psi}|^2
\end{equation}

as it should give me the probability to be in the state $\Phi_n$, which should mean to measure $E_n$?

Comment: I mean $\langle H \rangle = \langle E_\mathrm{old}|H|E_\mathrm{old}\rangle$ where $H$ here is the new Hamiltonian

Comment: Thank you I can calculate everything now except for the probability to find the system in the former ground state. For this one I really actually need the superposition, as I want to evaluate the integral of the product of $\Psi_{old}(x, t)$ and $\Psi_{new}(x, t)$? In the beginning I thought I could just evaluate the integral of the product of the old ground state with the new ground state like
\begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-ax^2\right) \exp\left(-a(x-\frac{qE}{m\omega^2})^2\right)dx
\end{equation}
There is an unknown constant $c_n$ in front of $\Psi_{new}$.

Answer (score 3):

If for $t<0$, the Hamiltonian is time independent and given by $\hat{H}_-$, you would solve the time evolution of the wave function using the time-dependent Schroedinger equation

$$ \hat{H}_- \psi_-(t) = i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi_-(t), \quad \psi_-(t_i) = \psi_i \quad t, t_i <0 $$

Given some initial condition $\psi_i$ at negative time (in your example, $\psi_i$ is the ground state wave function of $\hat{H}_-$), the time evolution is determined up to $t\to 0$, $\psi_-(0)$.

If for $t>0$ the Hamiltonian is different, and given by $H_+$, you can use the continuity of the wave function at $t=0$, meaning that you solve the Schroedinger equation for $t>0$ with initial condition given by $\psi_-(0)$

$$ \hat{H}_+ \psi_+(t) = i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi_+(t), \quad \psi_+(0) = \psi_-(0) \quad t >0 $$

The full wave function is then
$$ \psi(t) = \begin{cases} \psi_-(t), \quad t_i < t < 0 \\ \psi_+(t), \quad t>0 \end{cases} $$
and is continuous.

In your example, you begin with the ground state wave function of $H_-$. Let's call this wave function $\psi_-(x)$ as before. But this ground state wave function does not agree with the ground state of $H_+$. You can formally expand $\psi_-(x)$ in the eigenbasis of $H_+$ so that

$$ \psi_- = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \psi_k $$
where $\psi_k$ are the eigenfunctions of $H_+$, and formally, $c_k = \langle \psi_k, \psi_- \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*_k(x) \psi_-(x)$ are the coefficients of the projection of $\psi_-$ in this new basis. Solving for the time evolution then yields

$$ \psi_+(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k \psi_k(x) e^{i \frac{E_k}{\hbar} t} $$

where $E_k$ is the energy of the eigenfunction $\psi_k$. This is neither an eigenstate of $H_-$ nor $H_+$, and the new average energy will be non-trivial.

Comment: When the state evolves can you find out with what probability the system is still in the ground state? Supposedly I should be able to give the explicit probability for that case. I can now calculate the expected energy in the new system and I can calculate the ground state energy of the new system, however to receive the probability to find the system in the former ground state, I'd actually need $\Psi_+(x, t)$ and I dont think that works without computer calculations?

Comment: This probability is given by $|\langle \psi_- | \psi_+(t) \rangle|^2 = |\sum_{k,k'} c_k c_{k'} e^{-i \frac{E_{k'}}{\hbar} t} \langle \psi_k | \psi_{k'} \rangle|^2 = |\sum_k |c_{k}|^2 e^{-i \frac{E_{k}}{\hbar} t} |^2  $ but I don't think this is trivial to explicit, unless $c_k$ turns out to be easily computable.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Then there must be a trick I don't see, because this was an exam question, where you only had about 20-30 minutes time.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the $t<0$ ground state and not the $t>0$ ground state on which you're projecting? Because this second one is much easier to treat. The proba would be simply $|c_0|^2$ and is given by an integral of product of gaussians one centered at 0 and another centered around some non-zero value, which is computable.

Comment: Im not really sure. "What is the probability that the particle is still in the ground state for t>0?". I thought this implies that we are talking about the old ground state. However lets say they mean the new ground state. I would just compute the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-ax^2\right) \exp\left(-a(x-y)^2\right)dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}\cdot \exp\left(-ay^2/2 \right)
\end{equation}
and $y = \frac{qE}{m\omega^2}$?

Comment: Yes, almost, up to the normalization constant for the gaussians. I answered your recent post in more details.